# how do I make an advance filter logic using search filter and checkbox filter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search filter and a checkbox filter, It works, but individually. Example, if I check a category it will filter but if I enter a text in search box, the category filter will disappear as if it resets the filter all over. As I said, they work individually :(

here is my javascript

```
    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;     

    function myFunction() {
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                found = false;
            } else {
                if (tr[i].id !== 'tableHeader'){tr[i].style.display = "none";}
            }
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
          if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
            var vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
              return this.value;
            }).get();
            $('#myTable tr')
            .hide()    // 1
            .filter(function() {    // 2
            $('#tableHeader').show();
              return vals.indexOf($(this).find('td:eq(4)').text()) > -1;
            }).show();
          } else {
            // Show all
            $('#myTable tr').show();
          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate functions that filter same view. Each of the functions ignores the setting of the other (i.e., sets view only according to its triggering control).

You need to create one logic (e.g., function) that will consider the values of both - search input and checkbox. Then trigger this logic from these controls.